# Reasons for filament LED bulb failure?

Tags: led, mains, failure-analysis

I recently purchased a [filament LED bulb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LED_filament). However, when installed (AC 220V), it wasn't working well: it had a very low light. But sometimes (~ every 5min) it lights up for a few seconds at its normal power.

If the LED was really broken it wouldn't emit at full power, even for a short time. So what can be other problem to check?

NB: Doesn't seem to be a bad contact, it was very deeply plugged in the socket, and other bulbs work well in the socket.

Comment: think ... the light bulb requires something else to light

Comment: @jsotola Thanks! Mmm... Is a (tiny!) transformator hidden in the lignt bulb? I thought the LED was directly using the 220V.

Comment: no, i do not mean that ....  the light bulb requires a powered socket that makes a good contact with the bulb

Comment: Bad contact or bad bulb.

Comment: Some LED bulbs have a bulge above the Edison screw base that prevents them from going fully into the socket. If that's the case you can solder a lump onto the base to give it more penetration. I've done that  few times. Also, LED bulb QC can be a bit dodgy- I recently got 1 out of a pack of 3 bad bulbs from a Costco purchase, and that's far from a unique experience. They're not worth claiming warranty. There's actually a fair bit of circuitry in them.

Comment: I dont think anyone here understands how filament LEDs fail or how they work, but they do have much worse MTBF